# Is there a way to connect Wifi using PPPoE on Android?

Tags: android, wifi

Since I am newbie in Android, I don't know how to connect Android (2.1 on HTC Desire) with PPPoE using wifi connection.
So Please anybody know solution, then kindly help me.

Comment: Yes but what if you WANT to connect using PPPoe from the phone?
I have a number of pc's connecting through one router using different broadband connections and ISP accounts. The router is setup in bridged mode for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PPPOE client with android, you have to first root your android phone, otherwise, the application will not work.
The other method is to use your modem in PPPOE mode rather than bridge mode. In Bridge mode, you have to have a PPPOE dialer installed to your device to access the internet.

In PPPOE mode, the user id and password are punched in the modem itself, so you have to just provide the wifi (if enabled) password and you are connected to the internet. But there is a trick, some ISP's modem do not work, when switched to the PPPOE mode and have to be re-configured again.

Comment: I'm ready to accept the term that the phone should be rooted. then how can i proceed to develop an app. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can...
there is a App called [WiFipppoe](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cnddu.wifipppoe)...

**https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cnddu.wifipppoe**

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, PPPoE would be how you would authenticate to your service provider. Wifi just acts as a bridge between the router and the wireless device. The router is what should authenticate via PPPoE. Your device should connect to the Wireless Connection, that would put you on the same network as the router, the router authenticates to the service provider via PPPoE over the WAN.

Wifi is just a bridge between your device and the router. Now some routers have Wifi built in, but its like a Printer/Copier/Scanner, 3 devices jammed in to 1.